# How to propagate -Wno-dev to cmake using FetchContent_Declare?

Tags: cmake

I am using the `FetchContent` feature from CMake (3.12) and declaring it like this:

```
FetchContent_Declare(libsndfile
      GIT_REPOSITORY    ${LIBSNDFILE_GIT_REPO}
      GIT_TAG           ${LIBSNDFILE_GIT_TAG}
      GIT_CONFIG        advice.detachedHead=false
      SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libsndfile"
      BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libsndfile-build"
      CMAKE_ARGS        "-Wno-dev"
      CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
      BUILD_COMMAND     ""
      INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
      TEST_COMMAND      ""
      )
```

According to the CMake documentation:

> FetchContent_Declare: The <contentOptions> can be any of the download or update/patch options that the ExternalProject_Add() command understands

And according to the `ExternalProject_Add` documentation, "*The specified arguments are passed to the cmake command line*" when using `CMAKE_ARGS`.

The `-Wno-dev` option does not seem to be passed along as I continue to see this warning messages in the output:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /Volumes/Vault/misc/src/libsndfile/CMakeLists.txt:446 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0063 is not set: Honor visibility properties for all target
  types.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0063" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "sndfile-interleave" of type "EXECUTABLE" has the following
  visibility properties set for C:

    C_VISIBILITY_PRESET

  For compatibility CMake is not honoring them for this target.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I believe I am following the documentation but it seems I must be doing something wrong. Any idea what could be wrong?

Edit: As requested in comment, here is a complete example:

File CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(self_contained_libsndfile_example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# This is in order to trigger the warnings in FetchContent
set(CMAKE_C_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)

include(FetchContent)

set(LIBSNDFILE_GIT_REPO "https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile" CACHE STRING "libsndfile git repository url" FORCE)
set(LIBSNDFILE_GIT_TAG b4bd397ca74f4c72b9cabaae66fef0c3d5a8c527 CACHE STRING "libsndfile git tag" FORCE)

FetchContent_Declare(libsndfile
      GIT_REPOSITORY    ${LIBSNDFILE_GIT_REPO}
      GIT_TAG           ${LIBSNDFILE_GIT_TAG}
      GIT_CONFIG        advice.detachedHead=false
      SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libsndfile"
      BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libsndfile-build"
      CMAKE_ARGS        "-Wno-dev"
      CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
      BUILD_COMMAND     ""
      INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
      TEST_COMMAND      ""
      )

FetchContent_GetProperties(libsndfile)

if(NOT libsndfile_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(libsndfile)
endif()

set(LIBSNDFILE_ROOT_DIR ${libsndfile_SOURCE_DIR})
set(LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR "${libsndfile_BINARY_DIR}/src")
add_subdirectory(${libsndfile_SOURCE_DIR} ${libsndfile_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
file(COPY "${libsndfile_SOURCE_DIR}/src/sndfile.hh" DESTINATION ${LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories(${LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(target self_contained_libsndfile_example)

add_executable(${target} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${target} PRIVATE sndfile)
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example so that someone can run to try and debug the issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

With the fix of [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19854) CMake-issue, which will go into CMake 3.17, you could point variable `CMAKE_PROJECT_sndfile_INCLUDE_BEFORE` to a file which sets the CMake-policy CMP0063 appropriately and which will automatically be included before the call to `project(sndfile)`. As a result you won't get this warning for your fetched project.

Comment: I know it is a long time since my question but I guess I missed your answer. Thank you very much for pointing it out as this fix definitely seem to fix the issues I was trying to address!

Answer (score 3):

This is a misunderstanding of the CMake documentation.  The `CMAKE_ARGS` is part of the `Configure Step` options not `download or update/patch` options of the `ExternalProject_Add()` and is ignored.

Looking at the documentation for CMake (3.12) [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FetchContent.html]

> The contentOptions can be any of the download or update/patch
>   options that the ExternalProject_Add() command understands. The
>   configure, build, install and test steps are explicitly disabled and
>   therefore options related to them will be ignored.

To avoid the messages you see you need to invoke cmake as `cmake -Wno-dev` on the command line when building your project.

Comment: I think I finally figured out what you mean: the `FetchContent_Declare` [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FetchContent.html) states: _The <contentOptions> can be any of the download or update/patch options that the ExternalProject_Add() command understands. The configure, build, install and test steps are explicitly disabled and therefore options related to them will be ignored_ So this is why `CMAKE_ARGS` are being ignored.

Comment: Looks like you updated your response at the same time I was posting my comment... seems clear now that what I am trying to do will not work. Thanks.